Ставится ли тире в данном примере?

Красный подойдёт сюда лучше всего. Возможно — оранжевый.

Или вместо тире запятую? Как правильно?

Правильно:
Красный подойдёт сюда лучше всего. Возможно  — оранжевый.
Нужно поставить тире, это неполное предложение.
Сравнить с полным предложением: Возможно,  подойдет оранжевый.
Еще вариант: Возможен также  — оранжевый.
